# Why does conservative rasterization fail to call the fragment shader for some triangles?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math, opengl-4

I'm using conservative rasterization on a g3.4xlarge AWS EC2 instance. The following code should increment an atomic counter (read in RenderFunction()) in the fragment shader and store the fragment coordinates in a shader storage buffer object. The following triangle doesn't increment the atomic counter. Other triangles do result in the atomic counter incrementing.

nvcc --version output:
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
INFO: OpenGL Version: 4.0.0 NVIDIA 384.111

The following code is modified from https://github.com/daw42/glslcookbook

```
// g++ -std=gnu++0x  -g -I ./glslcookbook/ingredients/glad/include -I ./glslcookbook/ingredients  dbg1.cpp ./glslcookbook/ingredients/glad/src/glad.c ./glslcookbook/ingredients/glslprogram.cpp -ldl -lglut -lGLU

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "glslprogram.h"
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/ext.hpp>

#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "Chapter 2"

using namespace glm;

    int
    CurrentWidth = 576,
    CurrentHeight = 576,
    WindowHandle = 0;

unsigned FrameCount = 0;

GLuint
    VertexShaderId,
    FragmentShaderId,
    ProgramId,
    VaoId,
    VboId,
    ColorBufferId;

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);
void TimerFunction(int);
void IdleFunction(void);
void Cleanup(void);
void CreateVBO(void);
void DestroyVBO(void);
void CreateShaders(void);
void DestroyShaders(void);

enum BufferNames {
    COUNTER_BUFFER = 0,
    LINKED_LIST_BUFFER
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Initialize(argc, argv);
    glutMainLoop();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

GLuint buffers[2];
int width=576;
int height= width;
int gLog2SL=20;
int maxV=603979776;
GLuint maxNodes=66000;

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(gladLoadGL()) {
        // you need an OpenGL context before loading glad
        printf("I did load GL with no context!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    InitWindow(argc, argv);

    if(!gladLoadGL()) {
        printf("Something went wrong!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(
        stdout,
        "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
        glGetString(GL_VERSION)
    );

    glEnable(GL_CONSERVATIVE_RASTERIZATION_NV);
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: after calling glEnable(GL_CONSERVATIVE_RASTERIZATION_NV) : %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );
        exit(-1);
    }

    CreateShaders();
    CreateVBO();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(
        GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
        GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );


    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(
          stderr,
          "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
        );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
    glutTimerFunc(0, TimerFunction, 0);
    glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);
}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
    CurrentWidth = width;
    CurrentHeight = height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
    ++FrameCount;
     GLuint atomicVal=4352;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, buffers[COUNTER_BUFFER]);
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLuint), &atomicVal);

    GLuint zero = 0;
    glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, buffers[COUNTER_BUFFER] );
    glBufferSubData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLuint), &zero);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, buffers[COUNTER_BUFFER]);
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLuint), &atomicVal);

    struct NodeType {
        vec4 color;
    };

    //  NodeType nodeRA[maxNodes];
    NodeType nodeRA[66000];
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buffers[LINKED_LIST_BUFFER]);
    //  glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, maxNodes * sizeof(NodeType), &nodeRA[0]);
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 66000 * sizeof(NodeType), &nodeRA[0]);


    for (int i=0; i<atomicVal; i++) {
        printf("index= %d, %f, %f, %f, %f\n",i, nodeRA[i].color[0], nodeRA[i].color[1], nodeRA[i].color[2], nodeRA[i].color[3]);
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void IdleFunction(void)
{
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void TimerFunction(int Value)
{
    if (0 != Value) {
        char* TempString = (char*)
            malloc(512 + strlen(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX));

        sprintf(
            TempString,
            "%s: %d Frames Per Second @ %d x %d",
            WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX,
            FrameCount * 4,
            CurrentWidth,
            CurrentHeight
        );

        glutSetWindowTitle(TempString);
        free(TempString);
    }

    FrameCount = 0;
    glutTimerFunc(250, TimerFunction, 1);
}

void Cleanup(void)
{
    DestroyShaders();
    DestroyVBO();
}

void CreateVBO(void)
{
    glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
    GLint nodeSize = 5 * sizeof(GLfloat) + sizeof(GLuint); // The size of a linked list node

    // Our atomic counter
    glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, buffers[COUNTER_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // The buffer of linked lists
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, buffers[LINKED_LIST_BUFFER]);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, maxNodes * nodeSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    double pixSL= 1<<(gLog2SL);
    int m=11, n=13, p=15;
    GLfloat z= p*pixSL;
    GLfloat vertX1= 435275968, vertY1= 328189312, vertX2= 435275712, vertY2= 328189312,vertX3= 435275712, vertY3= 328189056;

    GLfloat Vertices[] = {
        vertX1, vertY1, z, 1.0f,
        vertX2, vertY2, z, 1.0f,
        vertX3, vertY3, z, 1.0f
    };

    GLfloat Colors[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(VaoId);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ColorBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Colors), Colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a VBO: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void DestroyVBO(void)
{
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ColorBufferId);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VboId);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not destroy the VBO: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void CreateShaders(void)
{
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    GLSLProgram prog;

    try {
        prog.compileShader("oit.vs");
        prog.compileShader("oit.fs");
        prog.link();
        prog.use();
    } catch(GLSLProgramException &e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    prog.setUniform("MaxNodes", maxNodes);
    // modelview matrix is a scaling by 1/max(x,y,z)
    double scale= 1.0/maxV, maxV1= maxV;
    const mat4 mv= glm::ortho(0.0, maxV1, 0.0, maxV1, 0.0, -maxV1);
    prog.setUniform("ModelViewMatrix", mv);
    glViewport(0.0,0.0,width, height);
}

void DestroyShaders(void)
{
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Here's oit.fs

```
#version 430


layout (pixel_center_integer) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;

struct NodeType {
  vec4 color;
  //float depth;
  //uint primID;
};

layout( binding = 0, offset = 0) uniform atomic_uint nextNodeCounter;
layout( binding = 0, std430 ) buffer linkedLists {
  NodeType nodes[];
};
uniform uint MaxNodes;


in vec4 ex_Color;
out vec3 out_Color;
void main(void){
    uint nodeIdx = atomicCounterIncrement(nextNodeCounter);

  // Is our buffer full?  If so, we don't add the fragment
  // to the list.
  if( (nodeIdx < MaxNodes-1) ) {
    float t2= float(nodeIdx);
    vec4 t1= vec4(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y, gl_FragCoord.z, 0.0);
    nodes[nodeIdx].color= t1;
  }

  out_Color = vec3(1.0, 1.0,0.0);
}
```

Here's oit.vs

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that those absurd values, after mangling them through some floating point operations and ultimately snapping the result to some fixed-point, result in a non-zero angle triangle?

Comment: Is this notion of absurdly values specified so that I can determine when a triangle is such? If the triangle has zero angle at some point in the pipeline manipulation why should it be ignored? If I create a bounding polygon such as in https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter42.html, even a single point becomes as large as a pixel. I would hope that the conservative rasterization implementation I'm using would handle all the cases of the method described in the link above.

Comment: " If the triangle has zero angle at some point in the pipeline manipulation why should it be ignored?" According to [GL_NV_conservative_raster](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_conservative_raster.txt): "Polygons with an area of zero **generate no fragments**, even for pixels that contain a vertex or edge of the zero-area polygon.

Comment: Also note the discussion in issue (2) in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

The comment in CreateShaders **says** "modelview matrix is a scaling by 1/max(x, y, z)" but that isn't what the ortho matrix actually **does**. My quick check of the math for vertX1 in Python shows it being well outside the viewport. If all three verts get clipped, no triangle, so no shader output.

Suggest re-reading carefully the description of an ortho matrix, or using a scale constructor/function instead.